# ERROR: could not insert 'fuse': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter

Tags: kernel, webdav, fuse

I was just wondering why my davfs2 mount no longer works:

```
root:/media# mount -t davfs https://XXX /media
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fuse': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
/sbin/mount.davfs: loading kernel module fuse failed
/sbin/mount.davfs: waiting for /dev/fuse to be created
/sbin/mount.davfs: can't open fuse device
/sbin/mount.davfs: trying coda kernel file system
/sbin/mount.davfs: no free coda device to mount

root:/media# modprobe fuse
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fuse': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

root:/media# rmmod fuse
rmmod: ERROR: Module fuse is not currently loaded

root:/media# ll /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 157K Jan 17 22:29 /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko
```

I am not sure what caused this. But I think there might be a problem with my kernel version:

```
root:/media# uname -r
    3.16.0-4-amd64

root:/media# dmesg
    [879073.041349] fuse: Unknown symbol sysfs_create_mount_point (err 0)
    [879073.041947] fuse: Unknown symbol sysfs_remove_mount_point (err 0)

root:/media# dpkg -l | grep linux-image
    ii  linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64        3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3         amd64        Linux 3.16 for 64-bit PCs
    ii  linux-image-amd64                 3.16+63                       amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)

root:/media# dpkg -l | grep fuse2
    ii  libfuse2:amd64                    2.9.3-15+deb8u2               amd64        Filesystem in Userspace (library)
```

I am running cron-apt, which recently upgraded the kernel and after three days libfuse2 - maybe there was a reboot between it. What I tried:

- reinstalled packages: linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64, libfuse2, dafvs
- update-grub (seemed to be OK)
- update-initramfs -u -k all (seemed to be OK)
- rebooted several times

Does anyone has a suggestion what to do, to solve the problem?
Thank you very - **very** - much.

Comment: Function `sysfs_create_mount_point`, required by your `fuse` driver, appears only in [kernel version 4.2](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=4.2;i=sysfs_create_mount_point), but your kernel is only 3.16.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how this could happen? I am only using the official stable repo for debian jessie.

Comment: Looks like something is broken with your installation or settings. You may try to load fuse driver via `insmod` using full path to the module. If this is succeed, then you have incorrect settings for `modprobe`. If this fails with same `dmesg` error, then you have kernel package broken, or someone replaces `fuse.ko` file in it.

Comment: `root:~# insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko  
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko: Unknown symbol in module  

dmesg: [14644.519399] fuse: Unknown symbol sysfs_remove_mount_point (err 0)  
`
**fuse.ko is from linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64, reinstalling does not fix the problem. Any other thoughts?**

Comment: So you have kernel package broken. Have no idea why.

Comment: Maybe this is the problem? 
root:/ # aptitude show linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
State: installed
Version: **3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3**
root:/ # uname -a
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian **3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u4** (2015-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: As your problem actually doesn't related to programming, but a software packages, you may receive better responce by asking on [ubuntu.se].

Comment: Moved to [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/735863/error-could-not-insert-fuse-unknown-symbol-in-module-or-unknown-parameter) - thank you very much @Tsyvarev

Comment: Maybe use jesse-backports repo and get 4.x kernel?

Comment: I had this problem with when kernel modules was build for another version of kernel.